# Disable cache only for newly modified scripts in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, browser-cache

Is it possible to disable the cache for scripts only (in chrome)? I would like to avoid reloading the entire web application (only reload the files I modified).

I know about hot reload, but sometimes I still need to restart the application.

Answer (score 0):

Go into More Tools>Developer tools. Under General Settings check off "Disable cache (while DevTools is open)"

EDIT: I found a Chrome Extension called [Cache killer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cache-killer/jpfbieopdmepaolggioebjmedmclkbap?hl=en), maybe you should check that out.